# Failed to load mod_mem_cache.so

Tags: apache2, memcached

I am trying to load `mod_mem_cache.so` in [SUSE Linux Enterprise Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_Server) 11, by doing
`LoadModule memcache /path/to/mem_cache.so`.

But I got this:

> httpd2: Syntax error on line 113 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 43 of /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf: Can't locate API module structure `memcache' in file /usr/lib/php5/extensions/memcache.so: /usr/lib/php5/extensions/memcache.so: undefined symbol: memcache

This memcached is installed using [Zypper](http://en.opensuse.org/Zypper), through our repository.

How can I fix this?

Comment: That question would probably be better asked on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Memcache is not a Apache extension, it is a PHP one. You will need to edit your PHP configuration to include the line:

```
extension memcache.so
```

From the looks of that error message, the extension is already in the default extensions directory, but if not, alter the `extension_dir` setting to read:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php5/extensions"
```

Then restart Apache, and check your [PHPinfo](http://help.rackspacecloud.com/article.php?id=082).

Comment: i didnt know mod_mem_cache and memcache are two different things :P